# the widgets dose not appear as i arranged it in android studio

Tags: android

When i was trying to make calculator program the buttons appeared like that when i ran the emulator [the appearance of widgets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKrWn.jpg) and when i rearrange the button 7 the widgets disappear [the widgets disappeared](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSrZU.jpg)
[the design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hopa.jpg).

**The activity_main.xml code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button17"
        android:layout_width="47dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button14"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button11"
        android:text="*" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button16"
        android:layout_width="47dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_marginEnd="48dp"
        android:text="/" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button15"
        android:layout_width="47dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button16"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button5"
        android:text="-" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button14"
        android:layout_width="47dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button15"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button"
        android:text="+" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button13"
        android:layout_width="47dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button11"
        android:text="7" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button12"
        android:layout_width="47dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button13"
        android:text="9" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button11"
        android:layout_width="47dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button12"
        android:text="8" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_width="47dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button3"
        android:text="6" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_width="47dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button3"
        android:text="5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="47dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button6"
        android:text="3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="47dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_marginBottom="136dp"
        android:text="2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="47dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button"
        android:layout_marginEnd="130dp"
        android:text="." />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="47dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_marginBottom="204dp"
        android:text="4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_width="47dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_marginStart="42dp"
        android:text="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="47dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button"
        android:layout_marginStart="132dp"
        android:text="0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="73dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="26dp"
        android:text="clear" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="197dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="79dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="134dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="194dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:text="TextView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**The MainActivity java code:**

```
package com.example.amr.calc;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend you to use Constraint layout

Answer (score 3):

You might want to give ConstraintLayout a go. The initial learning curve can be a little steep but it's worth it once you get it, you can build pretty much any layout with it.

I built the layout below for my own calculator app a while back.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:id="@+id/textViewInputOutput"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:textSize="38sp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewOne"
    style="@style/NumberText"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textViewFour"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textViewTwo"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewClear" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewTwo"
    style="@style/NumberText"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="2"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textViewFive"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textViewThree"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textViewOne"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewClear" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewThree"
    style="@style/NumberText"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="3"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textViewSix"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textViewDelete"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textViewTwo"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewClear" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewDelete"
    style="@style/NumberText"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="DEL"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewClear"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textViewClear" />

<TextView
    android:textSize="@dimen/operator_text"
    android:id="@+id/textViewDivide"
    style="@style/NumberText"
    android:text="÷"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textViewAdd"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textViewDelete"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewDelete" />

<TextView
    android:textSize="@dimen/operator_text"
    android:id="@+id/textViewAdd"
    style="@style/NumberText"
    android:text="+"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textViewSubtract"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textViewDelete"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewDivide" />

<TextView
    android:textSize="@dimen/operator_text"
    android:id="@+id/textViewSubtract"
    style="@style/NumberText"
    android:text="−"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textViewMultiply"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textViewDelete"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewAdd" />

<TextView
    android:textSize="@dimen/operator_text"
    android:id="@+id/textViewMultiply"
    style="@style/NumberText"
    android:text="×"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textViewSubtract"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewSubtract" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewFour"
    style="@style/NumberText"
    android:text="4"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textViewSeven"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textViewFive"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewOne" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewFive"
    style="@style/NumberText"
    android:text="5"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textViewEight"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textViewSix"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textViewFour"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewTwo" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewSix"
    style="@style/NumberText"
    android:text="6"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textViewNine"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textViewDelete"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textViewFive"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewThree" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewSeven"
    style="@style/NumberText"
    android:text="7"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textViewDecimal"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textViewEight"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewFour" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewEight"
    style="@style/NumberText"
    android:text="8"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textViewZero"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textViewNine"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textViewSeven"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewFive" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewNine"
    style="@style/NumberText"
    android:text="9"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textViewEquals"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textViewDelete"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textViewEight"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewSix" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewDecimal"
    style="@style/NumberText"
    android:text="."
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textViewZero"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewSeven" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewZero"
    style="@style/NumberText"
    android:text="0"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textViewEquals"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textViewDecimal"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewEight" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewEquals"
    style="@style/NumberText"
    android:text="="
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textViewDelete"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textViewZero"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewNine" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewClear"
    style="@style/NumberText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Clear"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewInputOutput" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewInputOutput">

</FrameLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewOpen"
    style="@style/NumberText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="("
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewClear"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textViewClose"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textViewClear"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textViewClear" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewClose"
    style="@style/NumberText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=")"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewOpen"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textViewDelete"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textViewOpen"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textViewOpen" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `RelativeLayout` which arranges views relative to each other, thus when you rearrange the button7 all the other widgets relative to button7 changes and so on. For that you have to make sure that any change in particular widget position does not affect the other. Apart form this (a simple approach) you can use `LinearLayout` or `GridLayout` for buttons in order to achieve the desired format.

Answer (score 0):

this kind of designing xml like that you do is not good and that is prefer to use linearLayout or do better but i found your problem 
the problem is because of this line

```
android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button11"
```

int the button 7 change the button 7 code to

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button13"
    android:layout_width="47dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button3"
    android:text="7" />
```

this will fix your problem

actually you put button 8 in the right of button 7 and then you put button 7 on top of button 8 your problem is something like this

i hope it help you (;

Comment: your welcome my friend if there was other question say i try to answer